# HTML 5 File Reader reading javaScript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, filereader

I'm trying to allow users to drag and drop a folder containing JavaScript files into an html5 page. This is what I currently have:

```
$scope.files = [];

//Establish dropzone
var dropbox;
dropbox = document.getElementById("fileDragAndDrop");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

//Events
function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
};
function dragover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
};
function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;

    for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i ++) {
        var entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
        
        if(entry) {
            traverseFileTree(entry);
        }
    }
};

//resursive file walker
function traverseFileTree(item) {
    if(item.isFile) {
         $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.files.push(item);
         });
    } else if (item.isDirectory) {
        var dirReader = item.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                traverseFileTree(entries[i]);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

So the dragging and dropping works, but I'm having problems reading the file content.

```
$scope.parse = function () {
    
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
        
            console.log(fileReader.result);
        };

        fileReader.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        };

        fileReader.readAsBinaryString($scope.files[i]);
    }
};
```

I am not getting any error messages, which makes it hard to debug. Am I doing something wrong? has anyone had any issues doing similar tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what your `$scope` is but giving it a go.

As you use `webkitGetAsEntry()` I assume this is for Chrome. From the looks of it your code *should* give you an error. If it does not, there is likely something you have omitted. You should typically get something like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

in your `$scope.parse` function.

---

There is a few issues. One is that you probably would read [files as text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsText) and not as binary string. Secondly `readAsBinaryString()` is deprecated, use `readAsArrayBuffer()` if you want to read binary data.

Further, the `webkitGetAsEntry()` returns a `FileEntry`, hence why you should get the error mentioned above. To read the file you could typically do:

```
$scope.files[i].file(success_call_back, [error_call_back]);
```

For example:

```
function my_parser(file) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(fileReader.result);
        };

        fileReader.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        };
        console.log('Read', file);
        // Here you could (should) switch to another read operation
        // such as text or binary array
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

$scope.files[0].file(my_parser);
```

---

This will give you a `File` object as argument to `my_parser()`. Then you could typically check `.type` and use appropriate read function. (Though be aware of the slackness in MIME type. As in: do not rely on it, but use it as a hint.)

```
if (file.type.match(/application\/javascript|text\/.*/)) {
    // Use text read
} else if (file.type.match(/^image\/.*/)) {
    // Use binary read, read as dataURL etc.
} else ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.parse = function () {

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (e) {

            console.log(fileReader.result);
        };

        fileReader.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        };

        fileReader.readAsText($scope.files[i]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working on mine, this is typescript

You should convert FileEntry To Standard File, before passing to FileReader.

```
const convertFileEntryToStandardFile = async (files: any[]) => {
    if (files) {
        let plainFiles = [];
        files.forEach(f=> {
            let plainFile = readFile(f);
            plainFiles.push(plainFile);
        });

        return  plainFiles;
    }
}

const readFile = async (fileEntry: any) => {       
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => fileEntry.file(resolve, reject));
  }
```